# Linux, C, epoll(), read() data incompleted?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

Linux, C. Below issue only happens by using epoll(). If I use select() on server socket, there is no data loss.

=============================

Update:
I received errno =11 (Try again) in read().
Do I need to continue, or break the while loop?

=============================

I have client side, send 1280 K data in 10 times (each time, I send 128K data);

I have server side, use epoll() to watch incoming data.

Once I got notified, I use below code to read data:

```
nbytes = Nread(current_fd, buffer, bytes_to_be_read);

int Nread(int fd, char *buffer, size_t count)
  {
          ssize_t r;
          size_t left = count;
          printf("===>\n");
          while (left > 0){
                  r = read(fd, buffer, left);
                  printf("data: %ld\n", r);
                  if (r < 1) {
                          printf("errno: %d\n", errno);
                          break;  //I do received 2 errors of Try Again. How to try again?
                  }

                  left -= r;
                  buffer += r;
          }
          printf("=> done, %ld\n", total - left);
          return count - left;
  }
```

In Nread, I expected to read bytes_to_be_read (65536) bytes and return.

But, when run the tool, I found server side just receive something like this. Look like I did not read all data from the buffer in some cases. Why?

```
1===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
2===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
3===>
data: 60734
data: 4802
=> done, 65536
4===>
data: 55934
data: -1
errno: 11
=> done, 55934  //data is not enough. the missing part should come soon. but why I am not notified?
5===>
data: 60736
data: 4800
=> done, 65536
6===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
7===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
8===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
9===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
10===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
11===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
12===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
13===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
14===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
15===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
16===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
17===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
18===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
19===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
```

===============

update:

if I use this code to read all data, then there is no bytes loss. but the performance is bad:

```
 36 int read_all(int fd, char *buffer)
 37 {
 38         ssize_t count = 0, bytes = 0;
 39
 40         while(1){
 41                 bytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
 42                 if (bytes < 1)
 43                         break;
 44                 count += bytes;
 45         }
 46         return count;
 47 }
```

===================================

## EPOLL()

```
efd = epoll_create1 (0);
event.data.fd = listener_fd;
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listener_fd, &event);

while (1){
    n_fds = epoll_wait (efd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, -1);
    for (i = 0; i < n_fds; i++){
                ...........
       if (islistener) {
             .....
            //handle new connections
       }
      else{
           bzero(buffer, recv_buf_size);
           if ((n= Nread(fd, buffer, recv_buf_size)) <= 0) {
                  //error
           }
           else
           {
                   //add bytes to total:
                    __sync_fetch_and_add(&(mythreads->total_bytes_transferred), n)    ;
           }

}
```

Comment: Because the 128K is not sent in a single chunk.  Evidently you had chunks totaling 60734 bytes that arrived (nearly) together, triggering `epoll`, and then enough delay before any more data arrived that your loop ran in the meantime.

Comment: In that case, I eventually I can receive all data from client. but current case is, I receive less data than client sends. for example, client sends 1310720 bytes but I just received 1301118 bytes.

Comment: If you think that is the case then show the rest of your code. Especially the code that calls `epoll` and `Nread` (in full context). It's likely you are just not reading all the data or interpreting the results incorrectly. For example, when you read less bytes than the full amount you need to keep track of that and a subsequent read needs to take that into account.

Comment: What is the transport layer?  TCP through local Ethernet?  TCP through the Internet?  Local loopback?  Unix socket?

Comment: You are in some weird half-way land between sensible blocking I/O and sensible non-blocking I/O. Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: read() gives you as much data as there is available. Just because you did 10 send() calls doesn't mean you'll do 10 recv calls. Also, ff your socket is non-blocking, you need to handle that properly, which your code seems to not do. Are you properly handling errno == EWOULDBLOCK, and go back to select or epoll and continue reading when there's more data available ?

Comment: Can you explain why you call `read` in a loop when you're already in an `epoll` loop? What purpose does the "loop in a loop" serve? (You may have a good reason for it. It's not always wrong. But it's unusual and suggests you may have some misunderstandings that may be causing you problems elsewhere.)

Comment: @David Schwartz I just want to fill in the buffer. recv_buf_size = 65536/64K

Comment: @SimonXiao Say you call the read loop to try to read 65,536 bytes and you receive 65,535 bytes. What's the point in calling read again? Surely if it had another byte to give you, it would have given it to you in the first call.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks! two questions: a) if the fd has data and I am notified by epoll_wait(). If the data incoming is 65538 bytes for example, but I just read 65536 bytes - do I get notified for the rest 2 bytes? -- I think I will not be notified again, right?    b) if so, how do I ensure that I read all bytes in the buffer once I am notified by epoll_wait()? Do I need a loop read until EAGAIN error received?

Comment: @SimonXiao a) It's up to you. If you use level triggering (which I strongly recommend) you'll get notified again. b) If `read` gives you all the bytes you asked for, you can call `read` again. You can also loop until `EAGAIN`. But if you use level triggering (the default), you'll get notified again.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks! But why I am not notified for the left/un-read bytes in my case? I used: event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET; DId I use something wrong?

Comment: I update the code again to reflect how many times of Nread called and how many bytes read each time. Why server side did not get notified for the missing bytes?

Comment: @SimonXiao Why are you using `EPOLLET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
```

You are doing edge triggered polling. Which means your last read is probably not reading all the available data. It stops after reading 64k data, even if there is more data available. But the poll will not trigger again due to the edge trigger. Suggest removing `EPOLLET`.

Answer (score 4):

```
        break;  //I do received 2 errors of Try Again. How to try again?
```

By going back to your epoll loop.

```
        data: 60734  //??? why I am not able to read all 65536 bytes?
```

Because they hadn't been received yet.

I think you may miss the big picture on how you do non-blocking I/O with `epoll`.

1. `epoll` tells you when there's data.
2. You read as much as you can at that time.
3. You go back to step 1.

Comment: I do have epoll() in a while loop to wait for notifications. The network is 40G Ethernet. I wait for 10 seconds and still not receive all bytes.

Comment: @SimonXiao Then you need to wait for more data, read that data, and e.g. append that to your buffer. But there's apparently a  bug somewhere in your code if you're missing some of the data. Aer you counting how much data you receive in total ?

Comment: @SimonXiao How many bytes did you send in total? How many bytes did you receive in total?

Comment: @David Schwartz, I send 1310720 bytes, but received 1174846 bytes. The output is updated in the top post.

Comment: @SimonXiao My bet is that your code that counts the bytes sent or received is wrong. Are you summing the return values of all calls to `Nread`? Are you taking into account that call to a send function may not send all the bytes you asked them to sent and you must look at the return values?

Comment: @SimonXiao Saves us all some time - show the poll loop and byte counting code.

Comment: @SimonXiao That does not show how you are counting the bytes and coming to the conclusion that the **total** bytes received is less than expected. Especially since you did not show the real code but a snippet. In particular what do you do in the N<=0 case? If you break or exit then that would be incorrect. You need to remove the `while` loop inside `Nread` and not break on error in the poll loop but just continue back to the `epoll`.

Comment: @AlanAu - this is how I calculate the total:             __sync_fetch_and_add(&(mythreads->total_bytes_transferred), n)

Comment: @SimonXiao And the rest of the points? How do you conclude that the total num bytes is not as expected. It's an infinete loop so at what point have you decided that there is no more data coming?

Comment: Add, I don't think the loop in Nread will make any difference. As you can see, the while loop is just executed once. // see it from the output: I sent 1280K in 10 times and received in 20 times (16 of them are 64K, 4 of them are less than 64K and lost....)

Comment: @Alanau yes, the server side keep listening and receiving data. will not exit. outside of this thread, I will get total bytes from mythreads->total_bytes_transferred.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90079/discussion-between-simon-xiao-and-alan-au).