# Linux, C, epoll() read: server did not get notified for the rest bytes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

This is new thread to discuss this topic: [Linux, C, epoll(), read() data incompleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661436/linux-c-epoll-read-data-incompleted?noredirect=1#comment53253331_32661436)

I have epoll() server socket use Level-Trigger mode.

Client send 10 * 128K data;

Server side, I used a buffer of 64K to receive, so I should be notified by at least 20 times to receive all bytes from client.

But my debugging shows that I am just notified 19 times and some bytes are missing! Why I am not being notified for the rest bytes?

========EDIT 1=======

Basically, client does send those bytes and those bytes should arrive to server side. (as I can receive them by another function of try best to read all bytes and return until no more bytes available for read - but that will cause the receive low performance).

But come to this Nread(), I should be notified and Nread should be called by 20+ times but now it is just called 19 times.

See code:

```
efd = epoll_create1 (0);
event.data.fd = listener_fd;
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listener_fd, &event);

while (1){
    n_fds = epoll_wait (efd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, -1);
    for (i = 0; i < n_fds; i++){
                ...........
       if (islistener) {
             .....
            //handle new connections
       }
      else{
           bzero(buffer, recv_buf_size);
           if ((n= Nread(fd, buffer, recv_buf_size)) <= 0) {
                  //error
           }
           else
           {
                   //add bytes to total:
                    __sync_fetch_and_add(&(mythreads->total_bytes_transferred), n)    ;
           }

}

int Nread(int fd, char *buffer, size_t count)
  {
          ssize_t r;
          size_t left = count;
          printf("===>\n");
          while (left > 0){
                  r = read(fd, buffer, left);
                  printf("data: %ld\n", r);
                  if (r < 0) { 
                          if (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN)
                                break;
                          else
                                return -100; //error
                  else if (r == 0)
                          break;
                  }
                  left -= r;
                  buffer += r;
          }
          printf("=> done, %ld\n", count - left);
          return count - left;
  }
```

The output:

```
1===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
2===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
3===>
data: 60734
data: 4802
=> done, 65536
4===>
data: 55934
data: -1
errno: 11
=> done, 55934  //data is not enough. the missing part should come soon. but why I am not notified?
5===>
data: 60736
data: 4800
=> done, 65536
6===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
7===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
8===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
9===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
10===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
11===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
12===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
13===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
14===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
15===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
16===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
17===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
18===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
19===>
data: 65536
=> done, 65536
```

Comment: You didn't get much joy the last time you asked this question. Because you are not making it easy for people to answer. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, `total` is used but not defined in `Nread`. How are we supposed to interpret the results when we have to continuously draw bits of information out of you? Please please provide an MCVE.

Comment: Thanks Alan - I update the code to reflect the total->count.

Comment: Returning -100 instead of -1 isn't any kind of an improvement to this code. It's pointless. You need to fix the *real* problems with this code, and your expectations, and your understanding of what you've now been told twice, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661436/linux-c-epoll-read-data-incompleted) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32706074/207421).

Comment: Well, `event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;` may be the reason as `EPOLLET` marks file descriptor events to be edge triggered, not level triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((n= Nread(fd, buffer, recv_buf_size)) <= 0) {
              //error
```

End of stream is not an error. See below.

```
//data is not enough. the missing part should come soon. but why I am not notified?
```

You *are* notified. That's why you did the next read. But you didn't just get the remaining `65536-55934` bytes, you got an entire buffer full next time.

You don't have any reason to expect 65536 bytes every time you issue a read. TCP can deliver one byte at a time if it likes. The only relevant question is whether you got all the bytes you were expecting, and you don't say that you didn't.

Other notes:

- If `r == 0` it is invalid to print `errno`. You aren't distinguishing between the two cases of error and end of stream.
- You also aren't distinguishing any of the error cases. It's only valid to re-read if `errno == EAGAIN`.
- I don't see the point of the `Nread()` method at all. It's just more code to break. Just call `read()` or `recv()` from inside the `epoll()` loop.